# Hive database or table cannot create, I have just configured a centOS 6.4 VM and installed hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, permissions, cloudera, bigdata

```
hive> create database bhaskar;
```

> FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied:
>   user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4891)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4873)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4847)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3192)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3156)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3137)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:669)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:419)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44970)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1760)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1756)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1754) )
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Comment: Ok I have solved this by my own! the commands are given below.


`# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse

# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod g+w /tmp

# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse

# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R XXXXXXX /user/hive/warehouse

# sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/hive/metastore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run hive query with root user and root is not the superuser in hadoop.
Follow below steps:

```
 >> sudo su hdfs
 >> hive
   >> create database bhaskar;
```

Comment: Sorry! Not Working

Comment: [training@hadoop ~]$ sudo su hdfs
bash-4.1$ hive
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/hdfs/hive_job_log_2b03b3b0-8600-4aab-b27b-f832de9499f0_478287008.txt
hive> create database bhaskar;
2017-07-31 00:03:08.082 GMT Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
----------------------------------------------------------------


hive> bash-4.1$